# Delphi: Addition and subtraction

Tags: delphi, addition, subtraction

I want to add and subtract numbers on a Delphi form. I have two buttons, one marked "+" and one marked "-".

If you click on the "+" button, obviously, it needs to add a number to a pre-existing value displayed in an edit box. The number in the edit box needs to be incremented by 1 every time you click on "+". If you click on "-", 1 needs to be subtracted from the value in the edit box. The value can NOT go beneath that of the pre-existing value, which is 35 in this case.

So my question is, how does the coding in Delphi look for this, and how do you declare the variables?

Comment: No. I'm teaching myself delphi because I like visual Pascal.

Comment: Why are you using `+` and `-` buttons? Use a `TSpinEdit` instead, and set it's `MinValue` property to 35. It's the way users expect Windows to work with integer values; it also handles keyboard entry in addition to button clicks.

Comment: It's a bit beside the point (not a direct answer to uour question) but I recommend you to head to this [blog](http://www.danieleteti.it/). Posts tagged under MVP & MVC may interest you. Don't forget to read all sections of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 2):

On your "-" button.click event add this code

```
 procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
  //declare all your variables here
  result : integer;
 begin
  result:=StrToInt(Edit1.text);
  if result=35 then
    exit
  else
    Edit1.text:=IntToStr(result-1);

 end;
```

on your "+" buttonclick  add this

```
 procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   Edit1.text:=IntToStr(StrToInt(Edit1.Caption)+1);

 end;
```

Comment: If I were you, I'd go for `TryStrToInt()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Write following code to your "+" button, "-" is not really different though:

```
Edit1.Caption := IntToStr(StrToInt(Edit1.Caption)+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.btnIncrementClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  j: integer;
begin
  j := StrToInt(edit1.Text);
  inc(j);
  edit1.Text := IntToStr(j);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnDecrementClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  j: integer;
begin
  j := StrToInt(edit1.text);
  if J > 35 then
  begin
    dec(j);
    Edit1.Text := IntToStr(j);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Your `btnDecrementClick` code is wrong. It doesn't prevent the value from going below 35; it decrements it if it goes over instead. (If the value is 36, you decrement it to 35. This is not what the question asks for the code to do.)

Comment: Huh?  The DEC never gets called unless the variable is greater than 35. I tested this and it works.

Comment: Read what I wrote again. The OP asked for the value not to go **below** 35; you're decrementing it if it's **above**, but not checking for it going **below**. (This means you can type `33` in the edit control, and then hit the decrement button to make it `32`, and your code doesn't prevent it from decreasing. The test should be `Dec(j); if j < 35 then j := 35; Edit1.Text := IntToStr(j);`, or something similar.

Comment: My bad. I assumed that because he was using + and - buttons that he was going to set the edit control to readonly.

Comment: Just read your comment again.. my code is fine, if a user types 33 in the edit control, the dec() never gets called, because I test to ensure the value is greater than 35.  It doesn't prevent a user from entering a lower number in the edit control, but the op didn't ask for that.