# How do I make a function to subtract and add values in a TEdit?

Tags: delphi, subtraction, addition, editcontrol

I'm new to programming, I'm looking to make a command to add and subtract values.

Where I would have a `TEdit.Value` with the initial value `0` and 2 more buttons, one of " + " and one of " - ", to increase or decrease the value, but I still don't know how to do that, can someone give me one light?

I looked up some examples of how to do this, but I didn't find anything that could help me.

Comment: In Delphi you use the `+` and `-` operators for addition and subtraction, respectively. This is documented.

Comment: To learn the basics, you should look for a book or publication about Delphi. E.g. google for "essential delphi" by Marco Cantú.

Comment: Duplicate of [Delphi: Addition and subtraction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8635966/4299358) and [Delphi: Arithmetic expression on Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Delphi_Programming/Arithmetic_expression) - I wonder what "_I looked up some examples_" means to you if you haven't found these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `StrToInt()` to convert the Edit's current `Text` string to an integer, then increment/decrement the integer, then use `IntToStr()` to convert the integer to a string and assign it back to the `Text` property. For example:

```
var Value: Integer := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
Inc(Value); // or Dec()
Edit1.Text := IntToStr(Value);
```

However, a better option would be to use a UI control that is specifically designed to handle numeric input, such as a [`TSpinEdit`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Samples.Spin.TSpinEdit), or a [`TUpDown`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TUpDown) attached to an Edit control.

Comment: A TSpinEdit is not only better for handling numeric input, but as it contains the buttons already, it's job done.